# Status - SyncStatusParam returns all objects

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to use SyncStatusParam to retrieve Status of an object. Instead it returned all objects that were even sent to QuickBooks cloud. If I go back to use the NgIdSet which has been deprecated, then it worked fine.

The XML I sent was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncStatusRequest xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId>
<SyncStatusParam>
<IdSet><Id idDomain="NG">11019504</Id></IdSet>
<SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
<ObjectType>Bill</ObjectType>
</SyncStatusParam>
</SyncStatusRequest>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML response you got back?

Comment: <OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId>
    <NgIdSet>
        <NgId>3256327</NgId>
        <NgObjectType>Customer</NgObjectType>
    </NgIdSet>

Comment: Try the above request with your ids

Comment: Thanks Jarred. NgIdSet is what I am using now. I am trying to switch to SyncStatusParam because I need to specify the DomainId.

Comment: The XML response I got back, is really long. Since it has every object that was ever synced with QuickBooks. It didn't filter by the Id I passed in.

Comment: You can try adding 'ErroredObjectsOnly="true" flag as a filter.As the name suggests,it will show objects which are in error state.
<SyncStatusRequest ErroredObjectsOnly="true" ...">